# Rails uninitialized constant MODEL in controller without model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I created Language controller under Admin namespace with 2 actions: index and toggle (created by "rails g"), but when I try to load admin/language/index I get the following error:

NameError in Admin::LanguageController#index

**uninitialized constant Language**

It looks like Rails is looking for Language model, is it? And how can I fix it if I have no intention to create Language model?

language_controller.rb:

```
class Admin::LanguageController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def toggle
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show your controller code please?

Comment: @uDaY, updated post with controller code

Comment: do you have some `before_action` in `Admin::LanguageController` or `ApplicationController`? for example `cancan` `load_and_authorize_resource`.

Comment: @gotva Yes, in application_controller.rb: `load_and_authorize_resource :unless => :devise_controller?`, `before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?`

Comment: `load_and_authorize_resource` tries to find `Language` model. You should skip it on this controller (try `skip_load_and_authorize_resource`)

Comment: @gotva How can I authorize users into admin part then? Should I create Admin model and authorize it and somehow bypass Language model? Found [this](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Admin-Namespace).

Comment: You can skip loading resource `skip_load_resource`. Check [documentation](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@gotva helped me to find solution:

As i'm using [CanCanCan gem](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) I should used `skip_load_and_authorize_resource` for language controller, also I organized my files as described in the [following cancan guides article](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Admin-Namespace).